# Why don't menu tabs show for a view generated page?

Tags: views, routes

Why don't menu tabs show for a view generated page?
Viewing my site as an administrator I see menu tabs above content pages for view, edit, and Devel (I have the developers module turned on).  When I generate a view page, the menu tabs are not displayed.  I have viewed video tutorials and they are present on a view page.  The view is working and generating the correct page. Is there a setting somewhere?

Added Question:
OK hansag answered my initial question below, so let me rephrase the question. The problem is I have created 3 pages in the view each with menu tabs assigned. The paths for each are:

default tab page= materials/%
page 2 = materials/%/general
page 3 = materials/%/scope

There is a contextual filter that takes the % value and finds articles with an attached taxonomy term.  The view page works since the placing a URL such as materials/termname finds the correct articles and displays them.

Why don't the menu tabs show?

Answer (score 3):

Those tabs are used for node editing. When you create a "page" from the views module it is general collecting a series of nodes on the page, so it is not displaying the single node tabs.

You might consider using this module. [Block Edit](http://drupal.org/project/block_edit)

It generates view/edit tabs for blocks and views.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Got it!!! But I have created several pages within the view with assigned menu tabs and they will not show either. Please see additions to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another answer as well.

In my example above, I had more than one tab defined, so even though the standard tabs such as "view" or "edit" did not show up, my additional tabs should have.

What I have found is that the menu tabs appear to only work if the path begins with 'user', 'comment, or perhaps a couple other key terms.  I was using 'materials' as the path root and this excluded the display.

I have posted an issue for the views module although I am not certain this is them or core.  Hopefully they can expand the functionality of the menu tabs to fit with path naming schemes of users.